# Getting The Most Recent Entry From The Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have four tables for *assigns*, *users*, *vehicles* and *fuel*. I want to make a query that would return unique rows (that's to say, there should be just one unique ID for each of the tables except the users table).

I want the query to return the most recent entry, (like the last one of its kind).

My current query is below but it returns the first row it finds, not the last of its kind

```
Select distinct
     v.vname,
     v.year,
     v.make,
     v.model,
     v.vid,
     v.fueltype, 
     f.fID,
     f.meter,
     f.date,
     a.driverID,
     a.dateassigned,
     u.uid,
     u.name,
     u.surname
 from
     vehicles as v,
     assigns as a,
     users as u, 
     fuel as f
 where
     v.vid = a.vID
 and
     a.driverID = u.id
 and
     v.vid = f.vID
 group by
     v.vid
 order by
     f.date desc
```

How can I get the last entry from the database using these tables?

Comment: Which column determines the age of the record?

Comment: Since MySQL 5.6 the result of GROUP BY and ORDER BY is random. [Implicit sorting by GROUP BY is deprecated in MySQL 5.6](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/21/heads-up-implicit-sorting-by-group-by-is-deprecated-in-mysql-5-6.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with limit :

```
   Select distinct
     v.vname,
     v.year,
     v.make,
     v.model,
     v.vid,
     v.fueltype, 
     f.fID,
     f.meter,
     f.date,
     a.driverID,
     a.dateassigned,
     u.uid,
     u.name,
     u.surname
 from
     vehicles as v,
     assigns as a,
     users as u, 
     fuel as f
 where
     v.vid = a.vID
 and
     a.driverID = u.id
 and
     v.vid = f.vID
 group by
     v.vid
 order by
     f.date desc 
 limit 1
```

Comment: This returns just a single row. Plus it's not the last entry in the database. Basically, I want to get just one last entry from the fuel table for each vehicle that was ever filled up. So there are a lot of vehicle fuel logs in the fuel table (and one vehicle appears more than once). So, say a vehicle has a vid of 43 (vid is the vehicle id from the vehicles table), and in the fuel table this vid may appear more than once. I just want to get the last entry for this vehicle... But I'm not looking for just the last entry for this one vehicle - last entry for all vehicles in the fuel table

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select distinct     
      v.vname,     
      v.year,     
      v.make,     
      v.model,     
      v.vid,      
      v.fueltype,       
      f.fID,     
      f.meter,     
      f.date,      
      a.driverID,     
      a.dateassigned,     
      u.uid,     
      u.name,     
      u.surname from vehicles as v, 
      assigns as a, 
      users as u, 
      fuel as f where v.vid = a.vID and 
      a.driverID = u.id and v.vid = f.vID 
      group by v.vid  
      order by f.date desc 
      limit 1
```

Any problems, please leave a comment.

Comment: _Never_ do a `GROUP BY` while selecting other non aggregate columns (unless the other columns are functionally dependent on `v.vid`, which I don't think is the case here).

Comment: It returns a single row which also doesn't contain data for that vehicle vid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
     v.vname,
     v.year,
     v.make,
     v.model,
     v.vid,
     v.fueltype, 
     f.fID,
     f.meter,
     f.date,
     a.driverID,
     a.dateassigned,
     u.uid,
     u.name,
     u.surname
 from
     vehicles as v,
     assigns as a,
     users as u, 
     fuel as f
 where
     v.vid = a.vID
 and
     a.driverID = u.id
 and
     v.vid = f.vID
 order by
     v.id desc 
 limit 1
```

If your table vehicles having id as primary key then above SQL will work.

Comment: You completely missed the point of the question. There existing query needs amending.

Comment: The query is a GET. It's not a POST. So I can't use the *LAST_INSERT_ID()*. Plus how can I do that to query data from those 4 tables?

Comment: I have considered here the latest v.id entry should display, as there is not mentioned which latest id has to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's what you want right now but I just want to throw it there for the next time you create a database. This thing is easily solved by **laravel** in it's approach. Just create two database fields `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Both fields are timestamps and `created_at` updates as you create a item whereas `updated_at` updates as one tries to update any field on database. 
This way you can get the latest records on the database wheather it was created or updated.

As there is slim to none chance of two timestamps colliding with each other you will almost always get one result. Also you can order the records this way according to timestamps of either created or updated.

Comment: The fuel table has a *date* column that stores the date on which the vehicle was filled up. The date for each vehicle are by no chance going to collide... So that's why in my query I am ordering them by *f.date*

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating that what you want is something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
    v.vname,
    v.year,
    v.make,
    v.model,
    v.vid,
    v.fueltype, 
    f1.fID,
    f1.meter,
    f1.date,
    a.driverID,
    a.dateassigned,
    u.uid,
    u.name,
    u.surname
FROM vehicles v
INNER JOIN assigns a
    ON v.vid = a.vID
INNER JOIN users u
    ON a.driverID = u.id
INNER JOIN fuel f1
    ON v.vid = f1.vID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vID, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM fuel
    GROUP BY vID
) f2
    ON f1.vID = f2.vID AND f1.date = f2.max_date
ORDER BY
    f1.date DESC;
```

This query just does an additional join to a subquery which finds, for each vehicle, the most recent date.  This restricts your current query by removing any records which are not the most recent, for each vehicle.

Note that I converted your old school implicit joins to *explicit* inner joins.  This is the preferred way of writing SQL queries these days.

Comment: This returns an empty result

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, and I think my logic is correct for what you are trying to do.  My guess is that your data has a problem.

Comment: Ok, let me post the schemas and then you can try to run the code from there, do you mind?

Comment: Setup a demo here: [Rextester](http://www.rextester.com).  Add some data that we may use.

Comment: Oh, hey, sorry for not rechecking how I was writing the code down (because I didn't copy - paste it)... I wrote u.uid instead of u.id. It does work but it gets duplicate rows for one vehicle.

Comment: @Kingsley OK...then there is probably a tie in that vehicle with two rows happening to have the same max date.  Am I right?  We can break the tie using some other column, if you can provide logic for how to break a tie.